# Moving entry point to DLL in a WinForm app

Tags: c#, dll, entry-point

I am trying to figure out a way to pre-process few things before my WinForm app loads. I tried putting static void Main() in a form within a class library project and commented it out from Program.cs. Which generated a compile time error: "...does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point". It makes sense since the program is not loaded, the DLL is not loaded either.

So the question is, is there a way to do this at all? I want the form in the DLL to be able to determine which form to launch the application with:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
   Application.EnableVisualStyles();
   Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

   if(condition1)
   {
      Application.Run(new Form1());
   }
   else if(condition2)
   {
      Application.Run(new Form2());
   }
}
```

This logic will be used in more than one app so it makes sense to put it in a common component.

Comment: You can certainly do this type of thing.  I don't see any reason to remove Main() from your WinForms executable.  How are condition1, condition2, etc being set?  What is happening that makes you say it's not giving the expected result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you just add a static method in your DLL that your application calls instead of doing the processing in main?

```
// In DLL
public static class ApplicationStarter
{
     public static void Main()
     {
          // Add logic here.
     }
}

// In program:
{
     [STAThread]
     public static void Main()
     {
          ApplicationStarter.Main();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep you Main method in Program.cs. Let it call a method in dll which instantiates a Form based on the condition and return it to Main.

Answer (score 0):

The "static void Main" method has to be within the "EXE" assembly, but you could have this method make a call to your shared assembly's version of "Main".  You just can't do it directly.

Answer (score 0):

static void Main() doesn't make sense in a class library, however your snippet of code should do exactly what you want if placed in Program.cs.

Also, do you need a catch-all 'else' clause, just in case condition1 and condition2 aren't met? May not be required, but in most cases I would expect some form of feedback rather than the application silently exiting - depends on what you are doing of course.

Edit: This might do what you want, if you simply need to separate the logic into a library

```
// Program.cs
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    if(MyLib.Condition1)
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    else if(MyLib.Condition2)
    {
        Application.Run(new Form2());
   }
}


// MyLib.cs
...
public static bool Condition1
{
    get
    {
         return resultOfLogicForCondition1;
    }
}
public static bool Condition2
{
    get
    {
         return resultOfLogicForCondition2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are trying to create a custom factory for the form to use for the application.  Something like the following:

In the EXE:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.Run(new Factory.CreateForm());
}
```

and in your library:

```
public static class Factory 
{
    public static Form CreateForm()
    {
        if( condition ) return new Form1();
        else return new Form2();
    }
}
```